# Apple Script: how to delete a file

Tags: applescript

I am trying to delete a hidden file that shows up every time I restart my computer with an Apple Script set to run on startup. I can't however seem to be able to correctly guess the path of this file.

The file's path is *Macintosh HD/Users/cristian/Dropbox (Hyperion)/Hyperion Team Folder/Icon*

If I move the file to the desktop and run the script bellow, it works.

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete the file "Icon
" of the desktop
end tell
```

My question is, how do I change this script to target the path above?
Also, is there anyway to permanently delete it not just move it to the trash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you can't correctly guess the location, then you tell us the location... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there is no new line character at the end of the file name this code deletes the file in the Dropbox folder and empties the trash.

Be aware that the `empty trash` command affects all items in the trash not only the currently deleted file.

```
set iconFile to ((path to home folder as text) & "Dropbox (Hyperion):Hyperion Team Folder:Icon"
tell application "Finder"
    delete file iconFile
    empty trash
end tell
```

Alternatively use the shell to delete the file, in this case the file will be deleted immediately.

```
set iconFile to POSIX path of (path to home folder) & "Dropbox (Hyperion)/Hyperion Team Folder/Icon"
do shell script "/bin/rm " & quoted form of iconFile
```

Answer (score 1):

just use a do shell script command "rm" which delete file directly (without transfer to trash), like in script bellow :

```
Set myFile to "Macintosh HD/Users/cristian/Dropbox (Hyperion)/Hyperion Team Folder/Icon"
try
do shell script "rm " & quoted form of myFile
end try
```

However, it should be better to understand root cause why this file is added every time, and then address this root cause.